# How do I authenticate/authorize myself to Quickbooks API?

Tags: c#, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I'd like to reach out to Quickbooks within my application to create some invoices.  I can do this when I go generate a temporary AccessToken and AccessTokenSecret but those expire.  How can I reliably and repeatedly make calls to the Quickbooks API?

Note:  The "user" accessing the data from my application can be considered "system".  I am using the Quickbooks API to simply streamline/automate a personal workflow.

```
string accessToken = "temporaryAccessToken";  //this expires
string accessTokenSecret = "temporaryAccessTokenSecret";  //this expires
string consumerKey = "myConsumerKey";
string consumerSecret = "myConsumerSecret";

m_OAuthRequestValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(
accessToken, accessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret);

string appToken = "myAppToken";
string companyID = "myCompanyID";
ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(appToken, companyID, IntuitServicesType.QBD, m_OAuthRequestValidator);

DataService service = new DataService(context);

var customer = new Customer();
customer.GivenName = "Scout";
customer.FamilyName = "Berman";

Customer resultCustomer = service.Add(customer) as Customer;
```

Comment: Tokens once generated using C2QB button do not expire until 180 days unless the C2QB button is used again by the same user(master admin) whereby new tokens are generated or tokens are renewed by calling Reconnect apis. Save the tokens corresponding to a user for a realm in your permanent store and keep a track of the number of days to know token expiry date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented in detail in [Intuit's documentation](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services).

You basically have two options:

**1. If you're building a SaaS app:**

Read the section about [implementing OAuth in your application](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0020_connect/0010_from_within_your_app#Implement_the_OAuth_Authorization_Workflow). It's vanilla [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) with a couple of button widgets added to push Intuit's brand on people.

Basically, you embed a javascript `script` tag in your header which pulls in Intuit's Javascript libraries, add a call to Intuit's Javascript `setup()` method, and put a custom HTML tag in your web page. This gets you a nice pretty "Connect to QuickBooks" button.

When you click that button, it kicks off a standard OAuth process which gets you a long-lived (6 months) access token. Store the tokens in your app so that you can make calls at any time using these OAuth tokens.

**2. If you're just building a one-off for your personal use:**

You can get a 6-month token by using Intuit's playground tool:

- https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA

**In either situation:**

You can make a REST API call to [renew the token](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/oauth_management_api#Reconnect) within 30 days of it's expiration date (e.g. you can just keep extending it to keep it valid forever and ever).

Comment: "implementing OAuth in your application" link is now a 404

Comment: "renew the token" link is also a 404

Comment: The problem I am having is at the bottom of #1. I have a successful connection, but how do I get the data that was returned. I'm clearly missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate accessToken and accessSecret corresponding to your target QB account.

https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA

[OAuth tokens are valid for 180 days](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0030_integrate_your_app/disconnecting_from_quickbooks/0040_handle_expired_or_invalid_oauth_tokens). You don't need to re-authenticate in every call.

If you want to know how it works in full fledged SaaS, then you can refer the following JAVA sample apps.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/sample_code/spring_sample_app_for_quickbooksapi

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Well, you could re-authenticate with every call, or, you could create a timer event, which would fire every minute, and keep the connection open.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  I am going through the IPP website to get my access key and updating a config with the new values.  What do you mean by re-authenticate with every call?

Comment: Well, I am not that familiar with QB API, but if you have a login method *authenticate), there is probably a logout too. IF that's the case, you could always login before performing an operation, and logout at the end of it. But the again, I am not an expert on QB API.